# Scrapy and github login

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am new to scrapy, and I've searched a lot, but I can't find any working example that can show how to do login with scrapy.

I've prepared this github login code to understand the flow pattern, but seems like it is not working ...

Can anyone show me how can to do this?

Thanks in advance.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.http import FormRequest

class SpiderOne(BaseSpider):
name = "spider"
allowed_domains = ["github.com"]
start_urls = ["https://github.com/login"]

def parse(self, response):
    print "in parse function"
    return [FormRequest.from_response(
        response,
        url='https://github.com/session',
        method="POST",
        formdata={
            'login':'valid_email',
            'password':'valid_password'
        },
        callback=self.after_login()
    )]

def after_login(self, response):

    print "in after_login function"
    print response
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shall try like this

```
def parse(self, response):
  print "in parse function"
  yield FormRequest.from_response(
     response,
     url='https://github.com/session',
     method="POST",
     formdata={
        'login':'valid_email',
        'password':'valid_password'
     },
     callback=self.after_login)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now I am getting status 200.

Comment: Done!

If you can show me, how I can catch the next response from github, I'll be very thankful to you!

I've made an request on: https://github.com/session
and I am getting results on this response: https://github.com/

Also, do I need to set a cookie for continue crawling?

Comment: May I know what do you mean by next response?

Comment: I am sending the form data on https://github.com/session,
but I am getting the "after login data / dashboard" from another response https://github.com/ .

And the crawler still stuck on the https://github.com/session. So it can't access the after-login-data.

So, how can I get the spider to crawl on the https://github.com/ instead of https://github.com/session

Comment: Why don't you try `https://github.com/login` instead of `https://github.com/session`?

Comment: it is throwing 404 error on https://github.com/login
_____
I've found it in the network tab
_____https://github.com/session  is to send the form-data
_____https://github.com/  brings the user homepage/dashboard data

_____I can send the data with the session, but I am stuck with it._____ how can I access the data coming from https://github.com/ response?

Comment: Mr.Prabhakar, Thanks a lot for your help. I have crawled the website successfully by changing the url in the return statement.

return self.make_requests_from_url("https://github.com/")